# Trying to add Mac OS X user, error "Name is used by another user"

Tags: macos

I am trying to add a new user to my Mac running Mac OS X 10.6.3.  When I am in the Accounts screen, I don't see the user listed, but when I try to add it, I get the error message "Name is used by another user".  This user name is not listed in /etc/passwd.

Any idea how to get this user really added to the system?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have this error with only this name, or for other names?

Comment: What username (long & short) are you trying to use?

Comment: Yes, this is the only user that I have the problems with.  The username is iufhelp and the long name is IUF Help.  It is not a reserved username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the user you want to create is a "ghost" user, who has no Home directory, so you might just want to delete the previously existing user account, if it has no more utility. To do this, complete procedure [on OReilly](http://www.oreillynet.com/mac/blog/2006/04/deleting_mac_os_x_users_remote.html)

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: 2020 Update: the useful bit of the O'Reilly link is the command `sudo dscl . delete /Users/<username>`, found via [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20120623143818/http://www.oreillynet.com/mac/blog/2006/04/deleting_mac_os_x_users_remote.html)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it works, but to fix things maybe you can try open a Terminal window, and run the command

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

You can also see all the users with the following command

```
dscl . -list /Users | grep "^[^_]"
```

It is also possible that your User ID is below 501, in which case it doesn't show in login window. To find if it is the case, enter the command

```
id <user_short_name>
```

Comment: Thank you.  The flush cache did not work.  It ran, but it didn't resolve the problem.  The dscl command does show this user, but I cannot login as the user.  I did a passwd on this user and it let me change the password, but I can't login and the user doesn't show up in the list of users in System Preferences.

Comment: One other thing, this user doesn't have a home folder under /Users.  So that is missing.

Comment: Don't you want to delete it? Is it an old user account to which you removed the Home account?

Comment: I didn't remove the home directory.  System Preferences locked up when I tried to create the account.  But if I can delete the user, then create it again, that would work.  Do you know how I can delete it when it doesn't show up in System Preferences?  Thanks.